# Java - how does Lock guarantee happens-before relationship?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, locking, volatile

Let's consider the following standard synchronization in Java:

```
public class Job {
   private Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();

   public void work() {
       lock.lock();
       try {
           doLotsOfWork();
       } finally {
           lock.unlock();
       }
   }
}
```

I understand, based on Javadoc, that this is equivalent to `synchronized` block. I am struggling to see how this is actually enforced on the lower-level.

`Lock` has a state which is a volatile, upon call to `lock()` it does a volatile read, then upon release it performs a volatile write. How can a write to a state of one object ensure, that **none of the instruction** of `doLotsOfWork`, which might touch lots of different objects, will not be executed out of order?

Or imagine that doLotsOfWork is actually substituted with 1000+ lines of code. Clearly the compiler cannot know in advance that there is a volatile somewhere inside the lock, therefore it needs to stop re-ordering the instructions. So, how is happens-before guaranteed for `lock/unlock`, even though it is built around volatile state of a separate object?

Comment: I don't see any volatile in Lock/ReentrantLock implementation. You can check ReentraltLock implementation at: http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.java/?v=source

Comment: Via its implementation. It isn't defined. Only required.

Comment: The state of AbstractQueuedSYnchronizer is a volatile variable

Comment: There is no guarantee that instructions in `doLotsOfWork()` will not be reordered between themselves. The guarantee is that they won't be reordered with instructions prior to `lock()` and subsequent to `unlock()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, if I understood correctly then your answer is [here](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/jmm/cookbook.html). volatile writes and reads introduce *memory barriers* : `LoadLoad`, `LoadStore`, etc. that *forbid* re-orderings. At the CPU level this is translated to actual memory barriers like `mfence` or `lfence` (the CPU forces the non-reordering via some other mechanisms too, so you might see something else in the machine code as-well).

Here is a small example:

```
i = 42;
j = 53;
[StoreStore]
[LoadStore]
x = 1; // volatile store
```

`i` and `j` assignments can be re-ordered between then, but *they can not* with `x=1` or in other words `i and j` can not go below x.

Same applies to the `volatile reads`.

For your example every operation inside `doLotsOfWork` can be re-ordered as the compiler pleases, but it can not be re-ordered with `lock operations`.

Also when you say that the compiler can not know that there is a `volatile read/write`, you are slightly wrong. It *has to know that*, otherwise there would be no other way to prevent those re-orderings.

Also, last note: since jdk-8 you can enforce non re-orderings via the `Unsafe` that provides ways to that besides volatile.

Answer (score 1):

From Oracle's [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#MemoryVisibility):

> A write to a `volatile` field *happens-before* every subsequent read of
>   that same field. Writes and reads of `volatile` fields have similar
>   memory consistency effects as entering and exiting monitors, but do
>   *not* entail mutual exclusion locking.

*Java Concurrency in Practice* states it even more clearly:

> The visibility effects of `volatile` variables extend beyond the value
>   of the `volatile` variable itself. When a *thread A* writes to a `volatile`
>   variable and subsequently *thread B* reads that same variable, the
>   values of *all* variables that were visible to *A* prior to writing to the
>   `volatile` variable become visible to *B* after reading the `volatile`
>   variable.

Applied to `ReentrantLock` it means that everything executed before `lock.unlock()` (`doLotsOfWork()` in your case) will be guaranteed to *happen before* subsequent call to `lock.lock()`. Instructions inside `doLotsOfWork()` still can be reordered among themselves. The only thing that is guaranteed here is that any thread which will subsequently acquire the lock calling `lock.lock()` will see all changes done in `doLotsOfWork()` before calling `lock.unlock()`.

Comment: I get that. This is high level description of JMM. I want to know how a write to a volatile variable entails that no reordering is in place that might screw it up, which compiler cannot know in advance (that there is state variable which is volatile)